# How to resolve Sourcetree node path issues after nvm setup?

Tags: node.js, git, atlassian-sourcetree

Sourcetree starting throwing error as below after having nvm setup with multiple versions of node. Sourcetree unable to find the exact nodepath.

**How to set default nodePath to target for Sourcetree?**

```
Info: can't find node in PATH, trying to find a node binary on your system

/Users/project-ui/node_modules/husky/run.js:8
  message(requiredVersion) {
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
Completed successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I managed with couple of steps**

`which node`: `/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.2/bin/node`

I included that to path variable inside bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.2/bin:$PATH"
```

Worked like charm